# Javascript input that automatically adds '/' to a date

Tags: javascript, date

I have found the code below, that automatically adds '/' to an input with a date. I was wondering if there was a way instead of adding a '/' I could add a '-'? I am not very good with javascript and would appreciate any help.

```html
<input id="dob" type="text" onkeyup="getAge()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function getAge() {
document.getElementById("dob").value=document.getElementById("dob").value.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for. I made the following adjustments to your original code:

- used a variable to call the "dob" element to save lines of code
- added event listener because that is preferable to declaring it in your HTML (so say the fancy developers)
- changed "keyup" event to be "keydown", because I think it is more reliable
- added maxlength to the input so that user cannot add more digits than a date should have
- added placeholder to the input so user will know what format they should be able to enter
- changed your RegEx to search for - instead of /

N.B. I have not added error checking to make sure user entered a "real" date (i.e. "02-31-2018") would not be caught.

```js
var dob = document.getElementById("dob");
dob.addEventListener("keydown", getAge);
function getAge() {
 dob.value = dob.value.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,"$1-$2").replace(/^(\d\d\-\d\d)(\d+)$/g,"$1-$2").replace(/[^\d\-]/g,'');
}
```

```html
<input id="dob" maxlength="10" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" type="text" />
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! How would I do the error checking for the date?

Comment: This isn't particularly functional. If I type "01-01-2018", then put the cursor at the start of the year (using either cursor keys or pointer) and press delete twice, I get "01-01-201" with the cursor at the end of the year. I'm sure there are any number of other cases where it misbehaves, e.g. it's also possible to remove all the dashes and dashes aren't added if I paste a value.

Comment: How could I make this more functional